# Is that able to have a transaction-wise global variable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

The situation is that: I have a function F1 which write into a buffer and the buffer will be write to external files when the function F1's fcinfo->flinfo->fn_mcxt is released; I also have a function F2 which depends on those external files, so when it runs, I want to make sure that all existing function F1's buffer (in this trasaction) have already write out to the external files. The two functions are independent, except when they are performed together.

As the result, I want that buffer to be a global variable in this transaction, so F2 can check it and decide if it is empty. If it is not empty, F2 can write it out manually.

Comment: [`SET LOCAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) would work, but only supports strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL uses multiprocessing, one backend cannot see the global variables in another backend.  You could write a `_PG_init` function that creates a shared memory segment for that purpose (see `pg_stat_statements`). That requires that your library is added to `shared_preload_libraries`.

A simpler alternative might be to use the `LISTEN` / `NOTIFY` facility of PostgreSQL to synchronize different backends.